Display a link source code from input form
I want to convert a twitter short link to the actual link it directed
Here's the link https://t co/hyVassZuxt
If you browse "view-source:https://t co/hyVassZuxt" on Chrome it will show you text
I have created input.php page that has form to send to my output.php :
<?php
  $link1 = file_get_contents('view-source:'.$_POST['input1']);
  echo $link1;
?>

but it shows

Warning: file_get_contents(view-source:https://t co/hyVassZuxt]):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\

What I want is something like
<head>
  <noscript>
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDy_i0UvAOI&amp;pp=ygUUbWlsa3NoYWtlIHJlZCB2ZWx2ZXQ%3D">
  </noscript>
  <title>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDy_i0UvAOI&amp;pp=ygUUbWlsa3NoYWtlIHJlZCB2ZWx2ZXQ%3D</title>
</head>
<script>
  window.opener = null; 
  location.replace("https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=PDy_i0UvAOI&pp=ygUUbWlsa3NoYWtlIHJlZCB2ZWx2ZXQ%3D")
</script>

that I can filter with str_replace and stuff (when I have figured out how to)

apparently it does not allowed to put shortlink but you know the link

I also have tried
<?php
  $link1 = file_get_contents($_POST['input1']);
  echo $link1;
?>



but it loads youtube page instead
(lmao this was dumb sorry)

well i still need it because sometimes it from www.youtube.com or m.youtube.com or other subdomain. is there any way to get it


To get the content with PHP you shouldn't use view-source:, PHP is not a browser. Use the normal URL: https:. Make sure that your webhost allows you to use this protocol and PHP is also configured to use it.

it loads youtube page if only the liink!

"but it load youtube page instead" - that's because you simply echo'd the HTML you received from the twitter short link - and that HTML code is what performs the "redirect" to YT, using a meta refresh. Do echo htmlspecialchars($link1); instead, and you will get the HTML code shown, instead of interpreted.

it is still not showing what "view-source" shows tho

That is because the t.co link recognizes that you're trying to access their redirect from something that isn't a browser, which it cannot redirect and doesn't support Javascript. It probably responds with some kind of error page. You need to send the correct request headers for it to respond with the redirect.

BTW, there's no need to escape / characters in the URL in location.replace(). The only place where / characters need to be replaced is in regular expression literals.

file_get_contents() follows redirects automatically. If you want to get the URL being redirected to, you need to use curl(). It only follows redirects when you enable CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION. The target of the redirect will be in the Location: header.

@Barmer, if you look in the code of the URL you can see there's a <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=....."> redirect. Not really a redirect in the literal sense, I know, but file_get_contents() doesn't follow it.
